# What are the common rules of chess rules that are lesser known

Tags: rules

Some of the chess rules are lesser known to beginners than others.
Can anyone suggest such rules, like En Passant, Three-fold repetition, Fifty-move rule, Stalemate, Castling Problems?

Comment: I am not sure how to give an opion-free answer here.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're looking for chess variants or looking for obscure rules in standard chess.

Comment: Maybe the OP is asking about _strategic_ rules.

Comment: The question seems to be: what are the less well known rules of chess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and suspect that when you say "rules are not much popular", you mean "rules that are lesser known".

I can think of two rules which beginners are known to struggle with: castling and en passant.

The concept behind castling is relatively simple, but beginners commonly struggle with the conditions that all must be "true" in order to castle successfully, which include never having moved your king and your king not walking through check to arrive to his final position.

From my experience, en passant is much more difficult for newbies to grasp. It is a special type of pawn capture where your pawn takes your opponent's pawn "in passing".  Details about this rule can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_passant

Comment: Insufficient Mating Chances should be listed here.